# How to copy a built-in array via copy-constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor

We know that a built-in array can neither be copied nor be assigned. So If it is a member data of a class/struct/union It is OK to leave the compiler do its magic to copy them:

```
struct ArrInt5{
    ArrInt5() = default;
    ArrInt5(ArrInt5 const&) = default; // OK 
    int a[5];
};

ArrInt5 a, b = a; // OK
```

- Sometimes that is not the case for example if the array holds objects of non-default- constructible objects. in that
  case we do need to define our copy-ctor to do the job:

  ```
    struct Bar{
        // deleted default ctor
        Bar(int x) : x_(x){}
        int x_ = 0;
    };

    struct Foo{
        Foo();
        Foo(Foo const&);

        Bar arr_[5];
    };

    Foo::Foo() : arr_{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    {}

    Foo::Foo(Foo const& rhs) : arr_{rhs.arr_[0], rhs.arr_[1], rhs.arr_[2], rhs.arr_[3], rhs.arr_[4]}
    {}
  ```
- As you can see `Foo` has a built-in array of five objects of type `struct Bar` that type is not default-constructible so the default ctor and the copy ctor must initialize it (`arr_`).
- The problem is: How could initialize that array if it is of a big size lets say 1 million element? Should I hard copy them element by element? or there's some workaround?

  - I know so many will recommend me to use the equivalent STL container `std::array` but I'm not on that topic, I'm asking whether there's a workaround for my built-in array of non default-constructible objects.

Comment: Not possible, AFAIK.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only solution _would be_ to use `std::array`, or to roll your own class that is equivalent to `std::array`. class types with array data members can automatically synthesize copying with default copy constructors, so that 1-level of indirection is needed to automatically generate this effect (irrespective of whether the underlying type is default-constructible)

Comment: `Foo(Foo const&) = default;` will correctly copy the array as it the first example. I don't understand the purpose of the question. Thus you don't need to define it, just ask the compiler to generate the default.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to generate this effect for you automatically is to wrap your array in a class type of some kind that has a compiler-generated copy constructor (e.g. such as a `default`ed constructor). In your particular example, you could just have `Foo(const Foo&)` be `default`ed:

```
struct Foo{
    Foo();
    Foo(Foo const&) = default;
    // This generates your:
    // "Foo::Foo(Foo const& rhs) : arr_{rhs.arr_[0], rhs.arr_[1], rhs.arr_[2], rhs.arr_[3], rhs.arr_[4]}"
    // by the compiler

    Bar arr_[5];
};
```

However the above only works if your copy-logic is trivial. For more complex copying, you can't always have a `default` copy constructor -- but we can solve this more generally.

If you wrap an array data member of any type/size in a `struct` or `class` and make sure it has compiler-generated copy constructors, then copying is easy in a constructor.

For example:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Array {
  ...
  T data[N];
};
```

This allows for the simple case of copying:

```cpp
Array<Bar,1000000> a = {{...}};
Array<Bar,1000000> b = a;
```

Or the more complex case of copying in a constructor that might require more logic than the compiler-generated ones:

```cpp
class Foo {
  ...
  Foo(const Foo& other);
  ...
  Array<Bar,100000> arr_;
};

Foo::Foo(const Foo& other)
  : arr_{other.arr_}
{
  ... other complex copy logic ...
}
```

At which point, congratulations -- you have invented [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)!
`std::array` was added to the standard library exactly because it was this simple to introduce a library-solution to this problem without having to alter the language itself. Don't shy away from it.